# One warning and main() returned garbage value

Tags: c++, oop, c++17, associations

Multiple students can associate with a single Department and single student can
associate with multiple Departments, but there is no ownership between the objects
and both have their own lifecycle. Both can create and delete independently.

WAP in C++ to model the relationships.

[image]

I have implemented this code as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    char* name_p;
public:
    Student(char *sName)
    {
        cout<<"Student constructor called\n";
        name_p=new char(sizeof(strlen(sName)));
        name_p=sName;
    }

    ~Student()
    {
        cout<<"Student destructor called\n";
        delete name_p;
    };

    char* sName()
    {
        return name_p;
    }
};

class Department
{
    char* name_p;
public:
    Department(char *dName)
    {
        cout<<"Department destructor called\n";
        name_p=new char(sizeof(strlen(dName)));
        name_p=dName;
    }

    ~Department()
    {
        cout<<"Department destructor called\n";
        delete name_p;
    }

    char* dName()
    {
        return name_p;
    }
};

class Course
{
    Student* std_p;
    Department* dept_p;
    char* courseName_p;
    static unsigned int index;
    static Course *courseList_p[4];
public:
    Course(char* crseName,Student* student,Department* dept)
    {
        cout<<"Course constructor called\n";
        std_p=student;
        dept_p=dept;

      if(index<4)
      {
            courseName_p=new char(sizeof(strlen(crseName)));
            courseName_p=crseName;

            courseList_p[index]=this;
            ++index;
      }
      else
      {
            cout<<"Cannot accomodate any more Course\n";
      }
    };

    ~Course()
    {
      cout<<"Course destructor called\n";
      delete courseName_p;
    };

    static char* findStudent(char *crseName, char* deptName)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
      {
        if ( (courseList_p[i]->getCourseName() == crseName) &&
             (courseList_p[i]->getDeptName() == deptName) )
        {
          return(courseList_p[i]->getStdName());
        }
      }
    }

    char* getStdName()
    {
        return std_p->sName();
    };
    char* getDeptName()
    {
        return dept_p->dName();
    };
    char* getCourseName()
    {
        return courseName_p;
    };
};

unsigned int Course::index =0;
Course* Course::courseList_p[4]={0,0,0,0};

int main()
{
    int i;

    cout<<"\nExample of Association class\n";
    cout<<"-----------------------------------\n\n";

    cout<<"We have got 4 students\n";
    Student *studentNames[4] = {new Student("Meera"), new Student("Moina"), new Student("Teena"), new Student("Mridula")} ;

    cout<<"\n";

    cout<<"We have got 2 Departments\n";
    Department *departNames[2] = {new Department("Mathematics"), new Department("ComputerSceince")} ;

    cout<<"\n";

    cout<<"Here class Course Associates Student and Department, with a Course name\n";
    Course course1("DataStructure",studentNames[0], departNames[1]);
    Course course2("Maths",studentNames[3], departNames[0]);
    Course course3("Geometry",studentNames[2], departNames[0]);
    Course course4("CA",studentNames[1], departNames[1]);

    cout<<"\n";

    cout<<"Finding a Student using Course and Department\n";
    cout<<"Student who has taken Maths Course in Mathematics Department is:"<<Course::findStudent("Maths", "Mathematics")<<endl;

    cout<<"\n";

    cout<<"Deletion of objects\n\n";

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        delete studentNames[i];
    }

    cout<<"\n";

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        delete departNames[i];
    }

    cout<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The code is showing warnings in main function i.e. ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to char* and also the main() function is not returning 0 but a garbage value. Please help me in rectify these errors and warnings.

Also I don't want to use this pointer in class course, can I implement the code without using this pointer.

Comment: Please run your code under a debugger.  Note that in your `Student` constructor you have `name_p=new char(sizeof(strlen(sName)));` followed immediately by `name_p=sName;` so there's a memory leak and you can no longer assume `name_p` points to memory that can be `delete`d.  Also, why not use `std::string` rather than raw `char *`?

Comment: `sizeof(strlen(crseName))` is either 4 or 8. I think you have combined two concepts (`strlen` and `sizeof`) by mistake. Also, `new char(v)` allocates *one* `char` with the value `v`, while `new char[v]` allocates an array of size `v`.

Comment: @G.M. as it is mentioned in UML class diagram that to implement above design we have to use char * only, can you please suggest how can I allocate memory in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code. Mostly they are related to the use of `char*` instead of `string`. I'm amazed to see that some teacher still are found of this practice.

### c-string allocation problems

The first problem causes memory corruption. This could explain that your `main()` returns garbage instead of 0.  For example:

```
name_p=new char(sizeof(strlen(dName)));  // OUCH!!!
```

In the statement you allocate it wrong. If you want to allocate an array, you must use `new[...]`. Moreover, keep in mind that a c-string allways needs 1 char more for the trailing null.  So it should be:

```
name_p=new char[strlen(dName)+1];
```

would already improve the situation.

Last but not the least,  if you allocate an array you must delete an array with  `delete[]`

### c-string copying issue

Then, you can copy C++ `string` with an assignment operator just as in:

```
    name_p=sName;   // OUCH
```

However,  for `char*`, this just overwrites the pointer that `new` returned and you are not sure that the c-string it points to will still be valid when it's used.

If you want to assign a c-string,  you need to go for:

```
    strcpy (name_p, sName);                       // C-style
    copy (sName, sName+strlen(sName)+2, name_p);  // Safer C++ alternative
```

### c-string comparison issue

Suppose you have two pointers to c string, say `pa` and `pb`.  Comparing the pointers looks at the memory address, not at the content.  So yu could have two identical strings but the comparison could nevertheless fail.    THis kind of comparison would work perfectly well for c++ `string`, but for cstring,  you need to to

```
    strcmp(pa, pb)==0        // instead of pa == pb
```

### c-strings in classes and structures

Whenever you have some pointers that you allocate in a class, you need to think of the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).  Meaning that you'd need to add a copy constructor and an assignment operator.  Fortunately, at first sight it seems that you don't need them here.  Of couse, if you'd use c++ `string` you wouldn't have to worry about such details.

### c-string conversion issues?

ANother issue in your code is the use of string literals with constructors.  For example:

```
new Student("Meera")....          // c-string literals (constant) 
Student(char*...)                 // constructor using a c-string pointer (non constant)
```

You can easily get rid of this complaint, by making the constructor's pointer argument as constant:

```
Student(const char *sName)...
```

The same applies to function arguments, such as in find.

### Other problems

The static member `findStudent()` works well, but only if a result is found.  If nothing is found, it's UB, since there is no return statement (put a `return nullptr;` at the end of this function?)

Moreover,  the wya you use this function, directly printing its result is dangerous, because dereferencing an invalid pointer will lead to UB.

[Here the corrected code](https://ideone.com/d51Ydt).  It compiles and seem to run.  I didn't analyse for more issues.